What the exact reason of the following insteresting phenomenon of eig(A,B) and eig(B,A)
Hellow, everyone!
I would like to ask a question about the generalized eigenvalue question:
If for
$$A*v = \mu*B*v$$
Where in some applications such as beamforming, the above equation has the following conclusions:
$$V^{H}*A*V=D=diag\{\mu_{1},...,\mu_{m}\}$$
as well as
$$V^{H}*B*V=I_{m}$$
We can use MATLAB's eig function.
[V,D]=eig(A,B)

to get the corresponding eigenvalue $D$ and eigenvector $V$.
Then I have the following question, when transforming
$$A*v = \mu*B*v$$
to
$$1/{\mu}*A*v = B*v$$
and we let $\sigma=1/{\mu}$, then get
$$\sigma*A*v=B*v$$
We can of course use
[W,F]=eig(B,A)

to find the corresponding eigenvectors and eigenvalues, where the eigenvalue matrix $F$ is the inverse matrix of the eigenvalue $D$ of the previous problem.
Why is it that $W^{H}*B*W=F$ as well as $W^{H}*A*W=I_{m}$ hold at this point instead of $W^{H}*B*W=I_{m}$ and $W^{H}*A*W=F$? I wonder to know the exact reason for the phenomenon?
